# How to fetch with axios after a post request in another view with react native?

Tags: react-native

How is it possible to fetch again the posts after I submit a form in another view?

This is the button I use for submitting:

```
<Button icon="plus" mode="contained" text="#1ebc61" color="white" onPress={() => {
   this.addHomework()
   this.props.navigation.navigate("ViewSubject")
}}>
```

How is it possible to fetch again in (ViewSubject) after submitting the form?

Comment: you can fetch in your viewsubject component again for example in componentDidMount or you can pass threw params with your navigation and display them inside viewsubject

Comment: The thing is that I pass through `ViewSubject` before the form, so after submitting the form, it returns and `ViewSubject` will remain mounted... I want for the fetch to run again. Also, the fetch is indeed inside the `componentDidMount`

Comment: there is something like forceUpdate() but it shouldnt be used because it isnt within reacts lifecycle. Are you managing some state after the fetch? because a setState should update the screen for example

Comment: I don't get what you just said with `setState` I'm sure that has nothing to do with what you just said. I have a HomeScreen then it moves to ViewSubject and from there AddHomework. I can't pass from AddHomework a param to ViewSubject.

Comment: The structure goes as this: `HomeScreen->ViewSubject->AddHomework->ViewSubject`

Comment: sorry I have to go for today maybe gonna look tomorrow into it- basically i meant that this.setState updates the component so if ViewSubject depends on state changes a setState should update or could at least update it.